# Cloudinary breaks RSpec tests with `uninitialized constant Cloudinary`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails, cloudinary

Have initialised Cloudinary using the ways described in this Rails integration article here >> https://cloudinary.com/documentation/rails_integration

Here is the error:

```
NameError:
  uninitialized constant Cloudinary
# ./config/initializers/cloudinary.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
```

I am using these gems:

```
gem 'cloudinary', '~> 1.13.2'
gem 'activestorage-cloudinary-service'
```

Have researched about this a lot but could not find any solution.

Cloudinary is recognised when on the development console but shows uninitialized when on the test environment console.

How do we make this work?

Comment: Can you check if it's working for you without using `activestorage-cloudinary-service` as a dependency? 
As per https://github.com/cloudinary/cloudinary_gem/issues/377#issuecomment-570797843, it might be clashing with Cloudinary native ActiveStorage support.

Comment: Also, did you declare `cloudinary` in your test environment? 
https://cloudinary.com/documentation/rails_activestorage#active_storage_configuration

Comment: @RoeeBen-Ari, have declared it in there. How do we remove `activestorage-cloudinary-service` as a dependency for when in test environments? Thanks a lot for commenting btw.

Comment: Sorry, just bumped into this and realized I never answered. Probably not relevant anymore, but have you tried removing the gem completely? I mean this line:
`gem 'activestorage-cloudinary-service'`